# Bingo-alike game Probability, $\frac{1}{4}$ chance... $20$ times losing in a row.

Tags: probability

I am trying to determine the probability of the following game with the following conditions and I don t know where to start actually or how to do it. Thank you for anyone that is taking his/her time to reply to this thread, I really appreciate it .

Game : There are $80$ balls, each ball having a number from $1$ to $80$. Each number is unique , so balls $1$ to ball $80$ are in the game. Each draw there are $20$ balls extracted from the box. Those balls let s say are 20 random numbers from $1$ to $80$.

If I choose a correct number before that matches one of those $20$ I will win.

What are my chances to lose $20$ times in a row ?

Each time I will have a new random number from $1$ to $80$, and the numbers will be new random ones as well from $1$ to $80$.

So in a $\frac{1}{4}$  chance , for $20$ times in a row, what is the probability of me not getting them right ?

After I get a win, I play the game again and reset from try 1 to try $20$, like a progressive casino play. If I get to 'try' $20$ I lose everything. How many times can I play without getting to try $20$? in probability of course :)

Thank you again and I hope I can make myself understood.

Answer (score 1):

The rule of product says you can multiply the chance of independent events.  You have a $\dfrac 34$ chance of losing, so the probability of losing $20$ times in a row is $\left(\dfrac 34\right)^{20}\approx 0.317\%$.